# Apache Olingo OData 2.0 doesn't support Java 8 LocalDatetime (java.time)

Tags: java, java-8, odata, olingo

I am using Apache Olingo version number

```
olingo-odata2-core:2.0.11
olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-core:2.0.11
olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-ref:2.0.11
```

When I use `java.time.LocalDatetime` type in my JPA entity, I got following exception:-

```
Odata- JPA Type Converter: Type[class. java.time.LocalDateTime] not supported.
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because in file [JPATypeConverter.java](https://github.com/apache/olingo-odata2/blob/991604d2e74b3becab9240329e305948042c496d/odata2-jpa-processor/jpa-core/src/main/java/org/apache/olingo/odata2/jpa/processor/core/access/model/JPATypeConverter.java#L91) line 91 its hard coded to only accept the following

```
else if (jpaType.equals(Date.class) || jpaType.equals(Calendar.class) ||
        jpaType.equals(Timestamp.class) || jpaType.equals(java.util.Date.class))
```

I tried using the `XmlJavaTypeAdapter` to make it to accept LocalDateTime, it works fine for getting the value but while setting it errors out because in [JPAEntity.java](https://github.com/apache/olingo-odata2/blob/991604d2e74b3becab9240329e305948042c496d/odata2-jpa-processor/jpa-core/src/main/java/org/apache/olingo/odata2/jpa/processor/core/access/data/JPAEntity.java#L515) Line 515 it only picks the XmlJavaTypeAdapter if the parameter type is String, maybe this can be fixed in Olingo code or we can add LocalDateTime support in `JPATypeConverter`

Though not sure this would be worth the effort because I suspect Olingo 2 might be tied to JPA 2 which itself lacked support for `LocalDateTime`.

Simplest solution would be to use `java.sql.Timestamp` or one of the supported classes in place of `LocalDateTime`

Harder solution would be to raise a bug with Olingo and fix it in the codebase